# Google sign-in, how to trigger from js?

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Im using the basic flow to sign-in with google accounts using:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

and the google sign-in button:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-onfailure="onFailure" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

It works fine but, what I want is to trigger the button action when the page is loaded since my website requires auth to enter. It is no optional the sign-in. To summarize I want the google prompt showing up once the page is fully loaded. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I tried clinking the element in a script and works but chrome blocks pop ups and is needed to unblock pop-ups and redirections. There is a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can trigger click with `element.click()`. But I wouldn't open any popups just like that. Let users click themselves, no matter it's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click when the page is loaded.
In javascript, you can recognize the page is loaded.

First, find the google sign-in button,
then trigger its click.

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   // The page is fully loaded
   // trigger the signin click function
   let googleSignInBtn = document.getElementById("the btn id");
   googleSignInBtn.click();
}
```

You have to trigger the click event in this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
// html
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething">Button Auto-click</button>

// javascript
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
};

function doSomething(){
  alert("Click!")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. Can you explain how this triggers the Google sign-in that the question asks about?